# How can I use query with array

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, parameters

I made a procedure using array parameter in Oracle:

```
create or replace PACKAGE my_pkg AS

TYPE USER_ID_TYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

create or replace procedure my_proc (my_id varchar2, ids USER_ID_TYPE)
is
  xxxx xxxx xxxx ....
end;
```

And I want to test that in sqldeveloper.

how can i do this?

I tried it like this:

```
exec('1010', ('111', '222')) -> fail 

exec('1010', ['111', '222']) -> fail

exec('1010' ARRAY('111', '222')) -> fail
```

I just want to use procedure in sqldeveloper with array.

Comment: You'll have to create a pl/sql block like: Declare arr user_id_type begin exec my_proc... End;. Oracle is very restrict to user's types.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You can initialise a collection (`TABLE OF`) by just using the constructor (sort of) like that but not a PL/SQL associative array (`TABLE OF ... INDEX BY`).

Answer (score 6):

In the recently released 18.1 version of Oracle Database (available for free exploration at livesql.oracle.com and also on the [Oracle Cloud](https://blogs.oracle.com/database/oracle-database-18c-:-now-available-on-the-oracle-cloud-and-oracle-engineered-systems)), you can use a qualified expression to do just what you'd like: construct an associative array "on the fly" in the invocation of the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_pkg
AS
   TYPE user_id_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (50)
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc (
   my_id VARCHAR2, ids my_pkg.user_id_type)
IS
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('COUNT = ' || ids.COUNT);
END;
/

BEGIN
   my_proc ('steven', 
            my_pkg.user_id_type (1 => '111', 2=> '222'));
END;
/

Package created.
Procedure created.
COUNT = 2
```

Check out my [LiveSQL script](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_GAE2LUPS0UA1IU1SUIAZCB7W1.html) exploring qualified expressions for arrays in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

## If you really do want an associative array...

Write an anonymous PL/SQL block to call it:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9995b9/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  my_id VARCHAR2(10),
  id    VARCHAR2(50),
  key   NUMBER(8,0)
)
/

CREATE PACKAGE my_pkg AS
  TYPE USER_ID_TYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  PROCEDURE my_proc(my_id varchar2, ids USER_ID_TYPE);
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY my_pkg AS
  PROCEDURE my_proc(my_id varchar2, ids USER_ID_TYPE)
  IS
    i BINARY_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    i := ids.FIRST;
    WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
      INSERT INTO test VALUES ( my_id, ids(i), i );
      i := ids.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE
  ids MY_PKG.USER_ID_TYPE;
BEGIN
  ids(111) := '222';
  ids(42) := 'The Meaning of Life, The Universe and Everything.';
  MY_PKG.MY_PROC( '1010', ids );
END;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9995b9/4/1)**:

```
| MY_ID |                                                ID | KEY |
|-------|---------------------------------------------------|-----|
|  1010 | The Meaning of Life, The Universe and Everything. |  42 |
|  1010 |                                               222 | 111 |
```

## However, you probably just want a collection (array) not an associative array...

... then you can create the array and populate it in the constructor.

So, remove the `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER` from your type declaration:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75f54/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  my_id VARCHAR2(10),
  id    VARCHAR2(50),
  key   NUMBER(8,0)
)
/

CREATE PACKAGE my_pkg AS
  TYPE USER_ID_TYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);

  PROCEDURE my_proc(my_id varchar2, ids USER_ID_TYPE);
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY my_pkg AS
  PROCEDURE my_proc(my_id varchar2, ids USER_ID_TYPE)
  IS
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. ids.COUNT LOOP
      INSERT INTO test VALUES ( my_id, ids(i), i );
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
BEGIN
  MY_PKG.MY_PROC( '1010', MY_PKG.USER_ID_TYPE( '111', '222' ) );
END;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75f54/2/1)**:

```
| MY_ID |  ID | KEY |
|-------|-----|-----|
|  1010 | 111 |   1 |
|  1010 | 222 |   2 |
```